# Display results when I click on submit of my form with Colorbox

Tags: jquery, forms, get, submit, colorbox

Here is my code :

```
<form method="GET" id="form" action="index.php">
 <center> <input type="text" name="bdv"> </center>
 <center> <input type="submit" value="Resultat"> </center>
</form>
```

When I click on Resultat I want to display with colorbox.
What can I do ? thanks in advance

Comment: You want to show result immediately or after getting response from your server after submit form ?

Comment: I want to show result immediately after clicking on button

Comment: But in case your server return something like false means the operation is not successfully done that was you expecting after submit the form ?

Comment: I've found : `<form method="GET" id="form" >
 <center> <input type="text" name="bdv" id="bdv" value=""> </center>
 <center> <input type="submit" value="Resultat"> </center>
</form>`

And script :  `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() { 
    $("#form").submit(function() {
   var bdv = $('#bdv').val();
    $.colorbox({"opacity":"0.1", "width":"430px", "height":"295px", href:"resultatBureau.php?bdv="+bdv}); 
       return false;
    });
  });
 
});    
</script>`